# Comparing "2016-11-23 00:00:00.0" with "Tue Nov 23 00:00:00 UTC 2016" in Java

Tags: java, date, comparison

How can I compare a string of format "`2016-11-23 00:00:00.0`" comes from PostgreSQL with a Date object in Java "`Tue Nov 23 00:00:00 UTC 2016`".
I searched for different suggestions to solve this issue but still throwing  `Object cannot be converted to String`compilation error.

I tried

```
String string = "2016-11-23 00:00:00";
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
Date date2 = format.parse(string);
```

I need a `True` for `if (string = date)`
where date is defined as  `Date date;` earlier in the program

I am a beginner in Java. 
Extremely sorry if I am asking a duplicate question due to my limited knowledge

Comment: Your format is wrong. The `ss.S` is messing things up. Change the format to `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"` instead.

Comment: Can you show all of your code? The code you posted compiles just fine.

Comment: Try to replace  "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S"  with "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss".

Comment: My Code is as follows    `Date date; 
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
    int i =0;
    for (int d = 0; d < days; d++) { 
     date = DateUtility.addNDaysToDate(from, d);
     System.out.println( ob1[0][i] +  "-------------" + sdf.format(date));
     if (ob1[0][i] == sdf.format(date)) {
      System.out.println("Success");
      arr2[d] = 0;
      i=i+1;
     } else {
      System.out.println("Failed");
     }`

Comment: How did you obtain the string? Did you call `resultSet.getString()`? You could just call `resultSet.getTimestamp()` and compare your two `Date` objects directly.

Comment: prior to the above code I have `Map<Date, GoogleAnalyticsPropertyDTO> map = new HashMap<Date, GoogleAnalyticsPropertyDTO>();
   if (gaPropList != null) {
    for (GoogleAnalyticsPropertyDTO gaProperty : gaPropList) {     
     ob1[0][no] = gaProperty.getFromDate();
     ob1[1][no] = gaProperty.getWebpropertyName();
     ob1[2][no] = gaProperty.getUsers();     
     no=no+1;
     Date dateString = gaProperty.getFromDate();
     map.put(dateString, gaProperty);
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code works fine to compare two date objects:

```
  String string1 = "2016-11-23 00:00:00";
  DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
  Date date1 = format.parse(string1);

   if(date1.equals(postgresDate)) { //postgresDate loaded from database
     //add your code
   }
```

**Note:** If you need to `parse` with string `2016-11-23 00:00:00.0`, then your date format should be `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your requirement you want to compare two dates in different formats.
There are various ways to do this :

**Precaution :**
use getTime() method to get the time in milliseconds and compare the dates,This will compare the dates at milliseconds precision which means 03-12-2016 00-12-12
 may be considered as different dates because one second has 1000 milliseconds.
so  03-12-2016 00-12-12 000 and 03-12-2016 00-12-12 500 are different dates for getTime() method.

```
 public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{
  SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
  Date datePG = new Date();//sdf1.parse("2016-11-23 00:00:00.0");
  int i=0;
  System.out.println(datePG.getTime());//1480795729834
 while(i!=100000 ){
    i++;
 }
 Date dateObj= new Date(); 
 DateComparison dc= new DateComparison();
 System.out.println(dateObj.getTime());//1480795671755
}
```

> purpose of while loop is to introduce a delay of few milliseconds.
>   you can see here without while loop i.e. without delay

```
public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
    Date datePG = new Date();//1480796286386
    Date dateObj= new Date();//1480796286386

}
```

both dates appears to be same.So if you are going to use getTime() for comparison be careful.

**Method 1:** : using getTime() method.

```
  public class DateComparison   {
        public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{
           SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
           Date datePG = sdf1.parse("2016-11-23 00:00:00.0");
           Date dateObj= new Date();  
           if(datePG.getTime()== dateObj.getTime()){
           System.out.println("Comparison using getTime() : "+"true");
           }else{
           System.out.println("Comparison using getTime() : "+"false");
           }
           System.out.println("Comparison  equals method:                            "+datePG.equals(dateObj) );

 }
```

**Method 2 :** : You  can convert the both dates to a common format and then you can compare them , for example suppose you want to compare only dates in yyyy-MM-dd format then you can use equals() method too.Here dates are converted in String and then compared. It is also an alternate way to compare date.

```
 public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{
  SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
  Date datePG = sdf1.parse("2016-11-23 00:00:00.0");
  Date dateObj= new Date();  
  DateComparison dc= new DateComparison();
  System.out.println("Comparison using String and compareDatesCommonFormat method : "+dc.compareDatesCommonFormat(datePG, dateObj));
}
//to compare in form of string 
 public String compareDatesCommonFormat(Date date1 ,Date date2) throws   Exception{
    String val=null;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String str1=sdf1.format(date1);
    String str2=sdf1.format(date2);
    if(date1.equals(date2)){
    val="equal";
    }else{
     val="unequal";
    }
   return val;
  }
}
```